# Exchange: Import mails to shared mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I've created a shared mailbox in my Exchange 2010...

> New-mailbox MySharedMailbox –shared –userprincipalname
>   someemail@mail.com

Is it possible to import mails to this mailbox? If so - how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export the existing mailbox as a PST. Connect to the new mailbox. Import the PST.

Comment: And if the emails are not in an exchange server, then connect to the mailbox with Outlook. Use the appropriate import routine. It's under the file menu (file, open & export in Outlook 2013).